# Interface's inheritance - Extend an interface in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I've started to convert a project's codes from java to Kotlin. I need to extend my BaseAppComponent interface. I've a problem about interface's inheritance. They are in same package.

But I see an error in AppComponent interface.

`"Error:(13, 26) Unresolved reference: BaseAppComponent"`

I shared my codes...  Where is my problem? I couldn't find any example about interface's inheritance on Kotlin.

```
open interface BaseAppComponent {

    fun inject(defaultApplication: DefaultApplication)
    fun inject(activity: BaseActivity)

    fun plus(comicListModule: ComicListModule): ComicListSubComponent
    fun plus(comicDetailModule: ComicDetailModule): ComicDetailSubComponent
}
```

---

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class, ServiceModule::class))
interface AppComponent : BaseAppComponent {}
```

---

UPDATE:

I could fix but I don't have any idea..

I created a new interface in AppBaseComponent file and I implemented that. After I refactored this interface to outside of that file... I couldn't see any differences between old and new interface, but It's working now..

Comment: You're doing it right in terms of syntax. You do not need to add "open" because this redundant for interfaces. How did you try to compile it?

Comment: Shouldn't `modules = arrayOf(AppModule::class, ServiceModule::class)` be `modules = *arrayOf(AppModule::class.java, ServiceModule::class.java)`?

Comment: @s1m0nw1 I tried clean-rebuild and also tried deleting all build folders... Nothing changed.

Comment: @Miha_x64 that line is about Dagger.. I removed all, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably check your gradle build. this can happen if you don't have a source set for Java and Kotlin both.

You can use the [default convention](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#kotlin-and-java-sources):

```
project
  - src
    - main (root)
      - kotlin
      - java
```

Or, if you putting your Java or Kotlin sources somewhere else, you can adjust the paths. For example, targeting JVM and using the Kotlin DSL fir Gradle, in your `build.gradle.kts` for that module:

```kotlin
plugins {
  kotlin("jvm")
}

sourceSets.main {
    java.srcDirs("src/main/myJava", "src/main/myKotlin")
}
```

I believe it is possible to place Kotlin and Java sources side by side within the same source set, and perhaps I could cook up an example for you, but it is not really advisable vs. the approaches above.

In general, if you can't find a class in IntelliJ or in your build, you should perform the following steps to diagnose:

1. **Is the class in question being compiled?** You can check this by confirming a `*.class` output for your `*.kt` or `*.java` sources.
2. **Is the class in question on the classpath?** If it is from a dependency, you can use `gradle dependencyInsight`; if it is a project class, you should examine your build files.
3. **Is IntelliJ synced with Gradle?** You will want to run the Gradle sync whenever you change the build files, so that IntelliJ can catch up (of course, unless you have automatic import enabled).
4. **Is the class accessible at your callsite?** This would probably surface as a different error in IntelliJ.

Obviously this answer assumes you are using Gradle, but all the same is true of Bazel, Maven, and so on, modulo syntax and approach.